# Did Lord Krishna have children?

Tags: krishna

Did Lord Krishna have children? If yes, what were their names? What did happen to them after Krishna's death?

Comment: His Very famous son name is Pradummna which is actually a re-birth of God Kama.

Comment: @Kedarnath- It is pradyumna not pradummna.

Comment: @Creator You are correct, Other [son's detail](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091013161914AAGEwNG)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, Lord Krishna had many children. As per Shrimad Bhagavatam the number was at least 161,080. Regarding His sons and grandsons, the scripture says their numbers were in millions:

> My dear King, the sons and grandsons of Lord Kṛṣṇa’s children numbered in the tens of millions. Sixteen thousand mothers gave rise to this dynasty. [SB - 10.61.19]

Shri Krishna had 16,108 wives and He had 10 children from each. Of His wives, 8 were principal and all their children's names are mentioned in the Bhagavatam. They are as below:

**1. Rukmani**

> The first son of Queen Rukmiṇī was Pradyumna, and also born of her were Cārudeṣṇa, Sudeṣṇa and the powerful Cārudeha, along with Sucāru, Cārugupta, Bhadracāru, Cārucandra, Vicāru and Cāru, the tenth. None of these sons of Lord Hari was less than his father. [SB - 10.61.11]

**2. Satyabhāmā**

> The ten sons of Satyabhāmā were Bhānu, Subhānu, Svarbhānu, Prabhānu, Bhānumān, Candrabhānu, Bṛhadbhānu, Atibhānu (the eighth), Śrībhānu and Pratibhānu.[SB - 10.61.12]

**3. Jāmbavatī**

> Sāmba, Sumitra, Purujit, Śatajit, Sahasrajit, Vijaya, Citraketu, Vasumān, Draviḍa and Kratu were the sons of Jāmbavatī. These ten, headed by Sāmba, were their father’s favorites. [SB - 10.61.12]

**4. Nāgnajitī**

> The sons of Nāgnajitī were Vīra, Candra, Aśvasena, Citragu, Vegavān, Vṛṣa, Āma, Śaṅku, Vasu and the opulent Kunti. [SB - 10.61.13]

**5. Kālindī**

> Śruta, Kavi, Vṛṣa, Vīra, Subāhu, Bhadra, Śānti, Darśa and Pūrṇamāsa were sons of Kālindī. Her youngest son was Somaka. [SB - 10.61.14]

**6. Mādrā**

> Mādrā’s sons were Praghoṣa, Gātravān, Siṁha, Bala, Prabala, Ūrdhaga, Mahāśakti, Saha, Oja and Aparājita. [SB - 10.61.15]

**7. Mitravindā**

> Mitravindā’s sons were Vṛka, Harṣa, Anila, Gṛdhra, Vardhana, Unnāda, Mahāṁsa, Pāvana, Vahni and Kṣudhi. [SB - 10.61.16]

**8. Bhadrā**

> Saṅgrāmajit, Bṛhatsena, Śūra, Praharaṇa, Arijit, Jaya and Subhadra were the sons of Bhadrā, together with Vāma, Āyur and Satyaka. [SB - 10.61.17]

Apart from these eight queens, Shri Krishna had 16,100 other queens and each had 10 sons each:

> *tāsāṁ yā daśa-putrāṇāṁ kṛṣṇa-strīṇāṁ puroditāḥ* [SB - 10.61.7]
>   -Among Lord Kṛṣṇa’s wives, each of whom had ten sons

So if we calculate thus, then the number would be around 161,080.

Almost all of these children and their grandchildren died due to the quarrel and fighting that ensued among them in the Prabhasa region and due to the submerging of Dwaraka under the sea. But the great-grandson of Shri Krishna, Vajra, the son of Anirudha (Anirudha was son of Pradyumna ) survived and was appointed as King by Arjuna as described in Mahabharata.

**Reference:**
Shirmad Bhagavatam, [Canto 10, Chapter 61](http://vedabase.com/en/sb/10/61)
Mahabharata, [Mausala Parva, 7](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m16/m16007.htm)

Comment: I don't think 10.61.7 necessarily means that Krishna had 10 sons with each of his other 16100 wives.  The verse just says that the wives who had ten sons were previously mentioned.  That doesn't mean that all the wives had ten sons.  The preposition tasya can go with puroditah.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I mean no offense but between what you think and what Shri Prabhupada or other saints have written, I'll give preference to them. And secondly, I don't know what *tasya* you are talking about, I had crosschecked the verse to confirm that it means each of His wives had ten sons.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the preposition tasam.  And I'm not asking you to take my word for it, I'm just saying there's an ambiguity in the verse, so it's possible that Prabhupada is interpreting it incorrectly.

Comment: I read somewhere that Lord Krishna had only ONE wife and her name was Rukmini.  He had only one son named Pradyumna.  He was a Grihasta Brahmachari.  It does not make sense for him to have 1000's of wives and sons.  The Lord is always a Brahmachari by nature.  This is because for the divine, "sex" becomes meaningless. (Source: Sri Krishna Charita, unconfirmed)

Comment: Lord Krishna and Sri Rukmani in addition to ten sons, also had a daughter who was married to son of kritavarma. This is mentioned in Srimad Bhagavatham

Comment: @Krishna Do you know what Srimad Bhagavatam chapter it's in?  You can read the Srimad Bhagavatam here: http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb

Comment: @Keshav -Lord Krishna's and Goddess
Rukmini's daughter with name Charumati is mentioned in Srimad Bhagavata (10.61.24)

Comment: How were these 1,161,080 children born? Why would Lord Krishna want so many children? Even if he wanted them, he must have used some mantra to give birth to so many children.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria He just duplicated himself so that he could be with every wife, as described in the Srimad Bhagavatam.  He wasn't going around single-handedly to every wire, which would have taken forever.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Why would there be a need for him to be with every wife? Taking in consideration the no. of children, the evolution must be of consciousness as mentioned in Srimad Bhagavatam.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Because as a husband he had a duty to every wife.  Here's what the Srimad Bhagvatam says "The Lord, performer of the inconceivable, constantly remained in each of His queens’ palaces, which were unequaled and unexcelled by any other residence. There, although fully satisfied within Himself, He enjoyed with His pleasing wives, and like an ordinary husband He carried out His household duties." http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/59 Narada later comes to Dwaraka and is shocked to see Krishna duplicated like this, simultaneously spending time with each wife, with his children, etc.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Well I was talking about how so many children were born, more than a lakh children can only be born using some special technique.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria The special technique is duplication.  Each duplicate would be with one wife, and so over the course of time the wife would have ten children.  Krishna wasn't going one by one to each wife and having children with them.  It would indeed be difficult for a single person to go around begetting over a hundred thousand children, but that's not what was going on.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan You really believe that's how those children were born? I think they were born using the same technique as Karthikeya.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, given that we already know that Krishna duplicated to be with each of his wife, the notion of each duplicate having ten children doesn't seem implausible at all.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan It doesn't make any sense to me that Krishna would duplicate himself just to have a lakh children. Did Lord Vishnu incarnated on earth just to do that?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, the goal wasn't to have a hundred thousand children, the goal was just to fulfill the responsibility of a husband to every wife.  And part of that responsibility is the begetting of children.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan giving 1 lakh children is a responsibility of a husband, really? I strongly believe that this figure is inflated.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria No, a husband doesn't have a responsibility to have a hundred thousand children.  But he didn't have that many children with a single wife.  Having ten children with each wife was not at all unusual.  What was unusual in Krishna's case is that he had so many wives, but he solved that problem with duplication.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I don't think Krishna, the purna avatar, would want 10 children with each wife. 10 children with each wife is very unusual.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I don't understand Keshav that you are seeing this as a common thing, there must be some very very special reason if this is true.

Comment: Did Krishna have daughters?

Comment: What about daughters?

Answer (score 5):

The details of Lord Krishna's family and His offspring from [ashtabharya's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashtabharya) [eight principal queen/consorts]

List of offspring classified as patrani's or ashtabharya's of Lord Krishna

1. **Rukmini**
   Pradyumna, Charudeshna,Sudeshna, Charudhena, Sucharu, Chharugupta, Bhadracaru, Charuchandra, Vicaru and Caru.
2. **Satyabhama** 
    Bhanu, Subhanu, Svarbhanu, Prabhanu, Bhanuman, Chandrabhanu, Brihadbhanu, Atibhanu, Sribhanu and Pratibhanu.
3. **Jambvanti**
    Samba,Sumitra, Purujit, Satajit, Sahasrajit, Vijaya, Citraketu, Vasuman, Dravida and Kratu.
4. **Nagnajiti**
    Vira, Candra, Asvasena, Citragu, Vegavan, Vrisha, Ama, Sanku, Vasu ,Kunti.
5. **Kalindi**
    Sruta, Kavi, Vrisha, Vira, Subahu, Bhadra, Santi, Darsa ,Purnamasa.
6. **Mitravinda**
    Vrika, Harsha, Anila, Gridhra, Vardhana, Unnada, Mahamsa, Pavana, Vahni and Kshudhi.
7. **Bhadra**
    Sangramajit, Brihatsena, Sura, Praharana, Arijith, Jaya and Subhadra.
8. **Lakshmana** 
    Praghosha, Gatravan, Simha, Bala, Prabala, Urdhaga, Mahasakti, Saha, Oja and Aparajita.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krishna)

Because of the unrighteous behaviour of Samba (the son of Jambavanti) all unrighteous Yadava's were wiped out from earth,Lord Krishna had warned them about this massive wipe out ([Yadavas wiped out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28Krishna%27s_son%29)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about my last question?

Comment: How all these children are born. Is it by physical contact of krishna with his wives? please clarify.

Comment: As per the wiki article you linked, Samba was actually the son of Krishna and Jambavanti. You incorrectly stated as the son of Satyabhama.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Lord Krishna said he preformed severe austerities to obtain Pradyumna as his son.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10012.htm

> That son whom I obtained through ascetic penances and observances of austere brahmacarya for twelve years on the breast of Himavati whither I had gone for the purpose, that son of mine, Pradyumna, of great energy and a portion of Sanat-kumara himself, begotten by me upon my wife Rukmini who had practised vows as austere as mine, that hero even never solicited this best of objects, this unrivalled discus, which thou of little understanding had solicited!

---

He did penance to obtain Samba also.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a015.htm

> "The blessed Krishna said, 'Bowing my head with great joy unto that mass of energy and effulgence, I said these words unto the great Deity, with a heart filled with gladness,--Firmness in virtue, the slaughter of foes in battle, the highest fame, the greatest might, devotion to Yoga, thy adjacence, and hundreds upon hundreds of children, these are the boons I solicit of thee,--So be it,--said Sankara repeating the words I had uttered. After this, the mother of the universe, the upholders of all things, who cleanses, all things, viz., the spouse of Sarva, that vast receptacle of penances said with a restrained soul these words unto me,--'The puissant Mahadeva has granted thee, O sinless one, **a son who shall be named Samva.**