# Did Gandhari Curse Krishna not to have son?

Tags: krishna, mahabharata

I heard story that *Gandhari* cursed to Lord Krishna that he will not have any son for his dynasty, when Krishna send Duryodhna partially naked instead of full naked.

But other side I see Krishna have sons. This is not related to [The question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/did-lord-krishna-have-children)

So which is the truth?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Did Lord Krishna have children?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/did-lord-krishna-have-children)

Comment: Nope, its a controversial Question do Krishna had or not? The question you said is about his son But I am asking do they have?

Comment: @cheenbabes i think question is clear but his facts are wrong.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Either way, this is a poor quality question. We expect it to at least be coherent.

Comment: @cheenbabes  agreed with that.

Comment: The event in question happened after Krishna had already had all His children. Therefore it's unclear if the question is whether Krishna would not have more children or (more likely) that they would be cursed to die. Poster should provide some kind of link to story in question from a bona-fide source.

Comment: "I heard story..." Please cite a reference to this story. (Blog posts are rarely acceptable, so mind that).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Gandhari cursed Krishna but with the death of all Yadavas in a manner similar to the death of her sons. So Krishna had children but they all met with same destiny.

The death of Krishna's sons is a part of [Mausala Parva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mausala_Parva) but the curse is given in the [Stri Parva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stri_Parva) of the Mahabharata.

For a good detailed answer, refer Keshav's answer: [Is there any story behind Lord Krishna's death?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/is-there-any-story-behind-lord-krishnas-death/2939#2939).