# Which of the Yadavas survived the destruction of Yadavas at Prabhas?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, yadavas

[Wiki page on Mausala Parva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mausala_Parva) has this to say about the destruction of the Yadavas -

> Soon everyone who is battling is dead, except Vabhru, Daruka and
> Krishna. Balarama survives because he was not at the fracas, and not
> inebriated.
>
> Balarama and Vabhru die next. Krishna asks Daruka to go to Pandavas
> ... Vasudeva dies next while he is meditating.

Which means everyone died but that can't be correct as Krishna's great grandson "Vajra" was appointed King later on as pointed out in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2512/2897):

> But the great-grandson of Shri Krishna, Vajra, the son of Anirudha
> (Anirudha was son of Pradyumna ) survived and was appointed as King by
> Arjuna as described in Mahabharata.

So, who all actually survived that conflict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Section 7 of the Mausala Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m16/m16007.htm) of Mahabharata gives an account of those that survived the Yadu Massacre.

After Vasudeva's demise Arjuna takes care of the remaining people and it is he that performs the funeral rites of all the dead. Seven days from then he sets out with the citizens and others to Indraprastha.

> Then Partha, more grieved than they, addressed those grieving and
>   cheerless citizens and officers who were more dead than alive, and
>   said these words that were well suited to the occasion: ‘**I shall take
>   away with me the remnants of the Vrishnis and the Andhakas.** The sea
>   will soon engulf this city. **Equip all your cars and place on them all
>   your wealth. This Vajra (the grandson of Krishna) will be your king at
>   Shakraprastha. On the seventh day from this, at sunrise, we shall set
>   out.** Make your preparations without delay.’

Here's an account of the people that went with him:

> The son of Pandu, having next performed duly those sraddha rites that
>   are done to the dead, quickly set out on the seventh day, mounting on
>   his car. **The widows of the Vrishni heroes, wailing aloud, followed
>   the high-souled son of Pandu.** Dhananjaya, on cars drawn by bullocks
>   and mules and camels. All were in deep affliction.
>
> **The servants of the Vrishnis, their horsemen, and their car-warriors
>   too, followed the procession. The citizens and the inhabitants of the
>   country, at the command of Pritha’s son, set out at the same time and
>   proceeded, surrounding that cavalcade destitute of heroes and
>   numbering only women and the aged and the children.**
>
> **The warriors who fought from the backs of elephants proceeded on
>   elephants as huge as hills. The foot-soldiers also set out, together
>   with the reserves.**
>
> **The children of the Andhaka and the Vrishni races, all followed
>   Arjuna. The Brahmanas and Kshatriyas, and Vaisyas, and wealthy Sudras,
>   set out, keeping before them the 16,000 women that had formed
>   Vasudeva’s harem, and Vajra, the grandson of the intelligent Krishna.
>   The widows of the other heroes of the Bhoja, the Vrishni, and the
>   Andhaka races, lordless now, that set out with Arjuna, numbered many
>   millions.**

However, on the path this procession is waylaid by Abhiras who carry off the women and wealth. Arjuna is unable to stop them and here is the final account of the survivors:

> The high-souled one, taking with him the remnant of the Vrishni women,
>   and the wealth that was still with them, reached Kurukshetra. Thus
>   bringing with him the remnant of the Vrishnis. he established them at
>   different places.
>
> **He established the son of Kritavarma at the city called Marttikavat,
>   with the remnant of the women of the Bhoja king. Escorting the
>   remainder, with children and old men and women, the son of Pandu
>   established them, who were reft of heroes, in the city of
>   Indraprastha.**
>
> **The dear son of Yuyudhana, with a company of old men and children and
>   women, the righteous-souled Arjuna established on the banks of the
>   Sarasvati.**
>
> **The rule of Indraprastha was given to Vajra. The widows of Akrura then
>   desired to retire into the woods.** Vajra asked them repeatedly to
>   desist, but they did not listen to him.
>
> **Rukmini, the princess of Gandhara, Saivya, Haimavati, and queen
>   Jamvabati ascended the funeral pyre. Satyabhama and other dear wives
>   of Krishna entered the woods, O king, resolved to set themselves to
>   the practice of penances.**
>
> They began to live on fruits and roots and pass their time in the
>   contemplation of Hari. Going beyond the Himavat, they took up their
>   abode in a place called Kalpa. **Those men who had followed Arjuna from
>   Dwaravati, were distributed into groups, and bestowed upon Vajra.**